# How to run Ubuntu 12.10 from pen drive?

Tags: installation

I seen the computer being run directly from the pen drive as in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgGbZfR6Vec
I want to run my computer from my pendrive too but I do not know how to do it. Can you please guide how could I install Ubuntu in my pendrive and run OS from the pendrive?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the steps outlined here: [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From_Windows)

You need to download Ubuntu first from: [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Enjoy!